# Do different workouts require different diets?

Tags: exercise, nutrition, diet

Would you recommended a different post-workout diet depending on the type of exercise - yoga class, lifting weights, long distance running, swimming?

Comment: Your question is very similar to "How long should I wait with eating after an exercise?" http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/543/how-long-should-i-wait-with-eating-after-an-exercise/565

Comment: This one does ask for slightly different details.  I'd be interested to hear the different recommendations for the different intensity workouts.

Comment: I would edit the first part of the question as it's already been addressed, and make sure the focus is on the varying exercises.  @SamBee

Answer (score 7):

If you are doing bodybuilding, or powertraining you should definitely eat **within two hours** after the workout. Your body, muscles, are in great need of protein, egg white, and -yes- even calories, to recover. It will take whatever energy supplies in your body to recover.

If you workout a lot, and don't eat enough, you will **not** put on any muscle.

The thing you need to think about is: how many calories/protein/egg whites does my body need - how hard was the work out? A normal full grown man should have an intake of 2000 - 2300 calories, depending on daily activity. You need to raise that to 2800 - 3000 if you do serious work outs, like body building.

If you do long distance running, or swimming, the problems you're most likely going to have are sore muscles, and cramps. To avoid these, you can eat bananas, and drink milk. Also, taking a very light extra dose ( available in powder ) of Creatine helps. Creatine keeps water in your muscles, and so lessens cramps and soreness.

If you're on a yoga class, i would recommend avoiding heavy meats, like Steak, ... and switch to chicken, which is easier to digest, and will not give you that "blown belly" feeling. Also look at what kind of vegetables you're eating. Some vegetables will give you more gas than others.

Comment: Most sources I've encountered so far suggests eating within 40 minutes after working out.

Comment: Well, I guess it depends from person to person. I cannot eat within the next hour after my workout as I feel so exhausted. When I'm more recovered, I am starting to feel more hungry.

Comment: when you say "put on muscle", are you talking about the muscle which is just for "looking good" or the muscle that actually gives us strength (allow us to do more pull-ups)?

Comment: @pacerier I'm sorry to only just now respond to your question. On Topic; one leads to another. If you are body building correctly, you will first gain strength, followed by a period of muscle growth. However, big muscles don't necessarily mean you can do "more" reps. In contrary, the opposite is more likely to be true. As bigger muscles require more oxygen, they are more likely to start burning sooner than slim muscles. Strength in a muscle has also to do with the strength of the joined tendon(s).

Comment: @UwConcept Nps =D so you do mean that body builders and weight lifters are two different things altogether?

Comment: @Pacerier Body builders are weight lifters, however weight lifters are not necessarily body builders. Of course more muscle will give you more strength, but the durability of your muscles will drop as they grow. I think this can be classified as subjective, but there is a difference in having a lot of muscle, and having muscle that "looks good", i.e. the lean muscle. But that's a story for an other Question :)

Comment: @UwConcept lol ok thx for the info =)

Answer (score 0):

Well yes definitely - nutrition after a yoga session will differ with nutrition after a long distance running session. It all comes down to what your goals are for training?
Are your goals fat loss, muscle gain, general health/wellbeing, training for a specific event? 
It also depends on the intensity of your workouts and the frequency/duration of these!